# Accessing Exchange shared folders using Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am creating an application to read emails and attachments from an account on a Microsoft hosted Exchange server (Office 365).  The difficulty I'm having is that I cannot find a way to get the MailKit API to see shared folders on the email account that I have connected to.

I can connect to my email account and see my Inbox and other folders that are under my main account. In Outlook, the tree-view of folders shows my main account (associated with my main email address) in the root, with the Inbox and other folders under that account.  Outlook then shows my shared folder name (associated with another email address) also starting at the root, with it's Inbox and other folders under it.  The shared folder (with its associated email address) does not actually have its own Exchange account to connect to.

When connected, I have examined the `ImapClient.SharedNamespaces` and `ImapClient.Others` collections and they are both empty.

Is there a way to see this type of shared folder in Exchange with MaikKit?

Answer (score 9):

This is possible by appending a backslash and the shared mailbox alias to the end of the username during authentication, here's some example code...

```
void Main()
{
    var userName = "main@user.com"; // The email address that has permissions to the shared mailbox
    var sharedMailboxAlias = "aliasName"; // This is the alias name as setup in Exchange
    var password = Util.GetPassword("Office365Password"); // Util.Password is a LinqPad method
    using (var client = new ImapClient())
    {
        client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
        client.Authenticate(userName + @"\" + sharedMailboxAlias, password);
        var inbox = client.Inbox;
        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
        Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

The shared mailbox alias usually defaults to the left part of the email address before the @

Updated: As per @Nischo comment - removing XOAUTH2 is no longer required. For more details: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/566

So removed the following line as it's no longer

```
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
```

Comment: For me it was possible in July 2020 without removing XOAUTH2.
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Sean on Jan 17 is correct. Note that you MUST remove the XOATH2 authentication as Office 365 does not support it even though it says it does when you first connect. MailKit then tries to use XOAUTH2 and has an internal exception when it fails to work. This is probably a bug in MailKit.